# How do I communicate with Android emulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm writing a Xamarin Forms application and I need to communicate with it from application running on host OS (Windows).

Tried using sockets to send UDP packets from Windows to Android emulator, but Xamarin Forms app doesn't receive any data.

What is the network configuration between emulator and Windows? Is there any other way of communication?

Comment: What emulator are you using?

Comment: The one that comes with Xamarin SDK tools for Visual Studio. Title bar says: "Android Emulator - Android_Accelerated_x86:5554"

Comment: If both are on the same network (and they should be) you can use IP address to communicate

Comment: I guess it has something to do with emulator's IP address being 10.0.2.15

Comment: Seems like I will have to use raw ethernet frames since I can't rely on adding additional routes. I'm not sure it is possible to handle them on Xamarin side, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. Basically, Android emulator doesn't have its' own network interface, so you have to use `adb` to forward required ports.

To forward a tcp port to the emulator, use:

`adb forward tcp:sourceport tcp:destport`

For example, to forward port 8000 on the host to port 8500 on the emulator, use:

`adb forward tcp:8000 tcp:8500`

To redirect a UDP port, telnet to the emulator's port (usually 5554) and then use redir:

```
telnet localhost 5554
redir add udp:sourceport:destport
```

As described here: http://www.iomem.com/archives/23-Redirecting-TCP-and-UDP-traffic-to-the-Android-emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

From the emulator name it doesn't look like VS emulator but I might be wrong.

If you are using VS emulator you can found out its IP and your Desktop machine IP as shown in the picture. Here emulator accesses the web page runs on host Windows which proves they can communicate.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it is a different emulator indeed. Here is a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/78yyJgT.png

Comment: I see IP address 10.0.2.15. What is the address of you desktop pc?

Comment: 192.168.0.102. But it seems that "10.0.2.15" doesn't actually exist in a physical network, it is a fake address inside an emulator. When emulator makes a request, it comes from my local IP and some random port.

Comment: check how you can configure your emulator to have access to internet. then it will work. To make sure you emulator has internet just go to browser on it and go to google or anywhere elase

Comment: I don't think it will work since emulator just forwards requests and doesn't have it's own IP address or dedicated port. Btw, internet connection was already configured and worked.

Comment: VS emulator does have its own IP address and it shown in the picture. If you are running on Windows I suggest to install VS emulator. The only thing to consider, it needs Hyper-V

Comment: Yeah, I tried with VS emulator and it works. The question is about Xamarin emulator that comes with an SDK.